# Complexity of factorial recursive algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, factorial

Today in class my teacher wrote on the blackboard this recursive factorial algorithm:

```
int factorial(int n) {
   if (n == 1) 
       return 1;
   else 
       return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

She said that it has a cost of `T(n-1) + 1`.

Then with iteration method she said that `T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 2 = T(n-3) + 3 ... T(n-j) + j`, so the algorithm stops when `n - j = 1`, so `j = n - 1`.

After that, she substituted `j` in `T(n-j) + j`, and obtained `T(1) + n-1`.

She directly said that for that n-1 = 2<sup>(log<sub>2</sub>n-1)</sup>, so the cost of the algorithm is exponential.

I really lost the last two steps. Can someone please explain them to me?

Comment: i would like to share an old thread which can be used. [Link_TO_Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991156/8395140)

Comment: The above written function goes into an infinite loop for factorial(0).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's start off with the analysis of this algorithm.  We can write a recurrence relation for the total amount of work done.  As a base case, you do one unit of work when the algorithm is run on an input of size 1, so

> T(1) = 1

For an input of size n + 1, your algorithm does one unit of work within the function itself, then makes a call to the same function on an input of size n.  Therefore

> T(n + 1) = T(n) + 1

If you expand out the terms of the recurrence, you get that

- T(1) = 1
- T(2) = T(1) + 1 = 2
- T(3) = T(2) + 1 = 3
- T(4) = T(3) + 1 = 4
- ...
- T(n) = n

So in general this algorithm will require n units of work to complete (i.e. T(n) = n).

The next thing your teacher said was that

> T(n) = n = 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> n</sup>

This statement is true, because 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>x</sup> = x for any nonzero x, since exponentiation and logarithms are inverse operations of one another.

So the question is: is this polynomial time or exponential time? I'd classify this as pseudopolynomial time. If you treat the input x as a number, then the runtime is indeed a polynomial in x. However, polynomial time is formally defined such that the runtime of the algorithm must be a polynomial with respect to the number of bits used to specify the input to the problem. Here, the number x can be specified in only Θ(log x) bits, so the runtime of 2<sup>log x</sup> is technically considered exponential time. I wrote about this as length in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647658/what-is-pseudopolynomial-time-how-does-it-differ-from-polynomial-time), and I'd recommend looking at it for a more thorough explanation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds like [Quasi-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial_time#Quasi-polynomial_time).

Comment: Reviving an old thread here, but I think it might be helpful to note that the teacher is correct. Because complexity is measured over an "efficient" encoding of the input. Factorial has a single int `n` as input, whose efficient encoding has size `log n`, not `n`! (See also my answer here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181268/finding-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-program/247451#247451)

Comment: @A.J.Rouvoet  sir  I'm sorry for reviving an old question; but sir I m trying to get this notion efficient encoding you have used, can you briefly explain this, I'm just curious to understand