# Pseudo-polynomial algorithms - math

Tags: complexity-theory

I understand when a given algorithm can be called pseudo-polynomial, however I can't find anywhere how to show it's exponential with respect to the size of input given in number of bits. What I mean here is formal proof that the relation between function of size of input and time complexity is exponential.
Maybe it would be easy to explain basing on knapsack problem.

Yes, I've read this thread: [What is pseudopolynomial time? How does it differ from polynomial time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647658/what-is-pseudopolynomial-time-how-does-it-differ-from-polynomial-time)

...but it's not quite what I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

(That was my original post, so I'd be happy to elaborate!)

Let's take the subset sum problem as an example. In this problem, we want to determine whether there's a subset of a set S of n numbers that adds up to exactly W. There's a pseudopolynomial-time DP algorithm that runs in time O(nW). Let's formally show that this is exponential in x, the number of bits of input.

To do this, we need to think about how you'd structure the input to this problem. If we were to write things out in plain English, we could write down an input to the problem by writing out all the numbers in S as a comma-separated list, appending the value of W at the end. For example, we might write the question "Is there a subset of {1, 2, 3, 8, 12} that sums up to 5?" by writing

```
1,2,3,8,12,5
```

This is done in decimal. If we write the numbers in binary, we get

```
1,10,11,1000,1100,101
```

To get the whole thing to fit into a single string of bits, we need to somehow encode these numbers and commas with separators interspersed. To do this, we'll use a standard trick. We'll double the bits of all the numbers, and replace the commas with the string 01. In this case, we'd get

```
110111000111110111000000011111000001110011
```

We can decode this input by reading off blocks of size 2. Every time we read 00, we know it's a 0. Every time we read 11, we know it's a 1. Every time we read 01, we know we've finished reading a number and should start on the next.

So how many bits are required here? Well, if there are n numbers, we'll have n separators, requiring 2n bits. If the numbers themselves have a total of b bits, we'll need 2b space to store them. Finally, we need lg W bits to write out W in binary, so we need 2 lg W bits to write out W. This means that the total number of bits, denoted x, satisfies

> x = 2(n + b + lg W)

So now look at the runtime of our algorithm, which is O(nW). If our input set consists of n copies of the number 1, then size of our input will be 2(n + 1 + lgW) = 2n + 2 + 2 lg W. If we now choose W to be equal to 2<sup>n</sup>, then the size of the input is 2n + 2 + 2n = 4n + 2. This means that x = 4n + 2, so n = Θ(x) and W = 2<sup>x</sup> = 2<sup>Θ(x)</sup>. Therefore, if the runtime of the algorithm is O(nW), the runtime is O(x 2<sup>Θ(x)</sup>), which is exponential in the size of the input.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might be helpful to point out how doubling W leads to an **exponential** increase in the number of bits needed to encode the input. The DP solution starts off by creating a table whose dimensions are $O(2^b)$ where $b$ is the number of bits needed to encode $W$.