# Finding a partition of a graph with no edges crossing partition

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph with a guarantee that it can be divided into two equal-sized partitions (one side may be 1 larger than the other), with no edges across this partition. I initially thought this was NP-hard, but I suspect it might not be. Is there any (efficient) way of solving this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve your problem in time O(n<sup>2</sup>) by combining together two well-known algorithms.

When I first saw your problem, I initially thought it was going to relate to something like finding a [maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) or [minimum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) in a graph. However, since you're specifically looking for a way of splitting the nodes into two groups where there are no edges at all running between those groups, I think what you're looking for is much closer to finding [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of a graph. After all, if you break the graph apart into connected components, there will be no edges running between those components. Therefore, the question boils down to the following:

1. Find all the connected components of the graph, making a note of how many nodes are in each component.
2. Partition the two connected components into two groups of roughly equal size - specifically, the size of the group on one side should be at most one more than the size of the group on the other.

Step (1) is something that you can do using a breadth-first or depth-first search to identify all the connected components. That will take you time O(m + n), where m is the number of edges and n is the number of nodes.

Step (2), initially, seems like it might be pretty hard. It's reminiscent of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is known to be NP-hard. The partition problem works like this: you're given as input a list of numbers, and you want to determine whether there's a split of those numbers into two groups whose totals are equal to one another. (It's possible to adapt this problem so that you can tolerate a split that's off by plus or minus one without changing the complexity). That problem happens to be NP-complete, which suggests that your problem might be hard.

However, there's a small nuance that actually makes the apparent NP-hardness of the partition problem not an issue. The partition problem is NP-hard in the case where the numbers you're given are written out in *binary*. On the other hand, if the numbers are written out in *unary*, then the partition problem has a polynomial-time solution. More specifically, there's an algorithm for the partition problem that runs in time O(kU), where k is the number of numbers and U is the sum of all those numbers. In the case of the problem you're describing, you know that the sum of the sizes of the connected components in your graph must be n, the number of nodes in the graph, and you know that the number of connected components is also upper-bounded by n. This means that the runtime of O(kU), plugging in k = O(n) and U = O(n), works out to O(n<sup>2</sup>), firmly something that can be done in polynomial time.

(Another way to see this - there's a [pseudopolynomial time algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647658/what-is-pseudopolynomial-time-how-does-it-differ-from-polynomial-time) for the partition problem, but since in your case the maximum possible sum is bounded by an *actual* polynomial in the size of the input, the overall runtime is a polynomial.)

The algorithm I'm alluding to above is a standard dynamic programming exercise. You pick some ordering of the numbers - not necessarily in sorted order - and then fill in a 2D table where each entry corresponds to an answer to the question "is there a subset of the first i numbers that adds up to exactly j?" If you're not familiar with this algorithm, I'll leave it up to you to work out the details, as it's a really beautiful problem to solve that has a fairly simple and elegant solution.

Overall, this algorithm will run in time O(n<sup>2</sup>), since you'll do O(m + n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>) work to find connected components, followed by time O(n<sup>2</sup>) to run the partition problem DP to determine whether the split exists.

Hope this helps!