# Why is the runtime of Knapsack Problem in terms of n and 2 number of bits of W

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, knapsack-problem

I recently began to understand what pseudo polynomial means thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647658/what-is-pseudopolynomial-time-how-does-it-differ-from-polynomial-time). However, a burning question of mine is why does the knapsack problem when used with dynamic Programming has a runtime of [image] and not [image]. Where n is number of items that are being considered for the knapsack and [image] which is the number of bits needed to encode W and [image] is number of possible states(values) given x bits. Considering that the formal definition of time complexity defines the size of a problem as

> The size of the input to a problem is the **number of bits** required to
>   write out that input.

Since number of bits for the weight is not fixed but rather variable, there are at most **[image] total number of bits** for all the possible values from 0 to W times the value n or [image]. With that being said why is the runtime for the knapsack when paired with dynamic programming has a runtime of [image] and not [image]. I know that [image] but time complexity refers to size of the input as **number of bits**. What assumptions am I making, or what piece of knowledge am I missing that would rectify the disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation related to the knapsack input size.

- The number of items *n* can be represented by O(lg *n*) bits;
- *n* item weights: noting that each item weight must be ≤ *W* (otherwise we can ignore those items weighting more than *W*), we can represent each item weight using O(lg *W*) bits for a total of O(*n* lg *W*) bits;
- *n* item values: let the maximum value be *V*. Then, each item value can be represented using O(lg *V*) bits for a total of O(*n* lg *V*) bits.

The total input size therefore is O(lg *n*+*n*(lg *W*+lg *V*)) = O(*n*(lg *W*+lg *V*)).

Let *b* = lg *W* and *v* = lg *V*. Then the input size is O(*n*(*b*+*v*)). Now, note that in the  O(*nW*) running time for the Dynamic Programming solution *v* doesn’t show up explicitly, so that the running time is O(*nW*) = O(*n2^b*).