# Time complexity for T(n-1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I am confused on solving this time complexity problem.

```
T(n) = T(n-1)
```

I know in quick-sort worst case `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(1) + n`

Which evaluates to `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1` & this geometric sequence equals `O(n^2)`

However. I see answers on stackoverflow that say `T(n) = T(n-1) + c = O(n)`.

How is this possible when this is also equal to `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1`, which equals `O(n^2)`

Can somebody please explain.

Comment: "T(n) = T(n-1)" - then T is just a constant function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T(n) = T(n-1) + c` isn't equal to `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1` because the terms being added are constants. Basically:

**Adding nothing:**

```
T(n) = T(n-1)
0 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 0
O(1)
```

**Adding a constant:**

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c
c + c + c + ... + c = nc
O(n)
```

**Adding a variable:**

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2
O(n^2)
```

Comment: That was a great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) -> T(n-1) = T(n-2) --> T(n) = T(0)
```

Which is 0 or O(1)

Comment: If this is true, then can you explain why `T(n) = a + T(n - 1)` is `O(n)`. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation

Comment: `T(n) = a + T(n - 1) = 2a + T(n - 2) = ka + T(n - k) = na + T(0)` which is `O(n)`.