# Using induction to prove time complexity of functions

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I want to find out the time complexity of this function by using induction f(n) = 0, if n = 0

f(n) = f(n − 1) + 2n − 1, if n ≥ 1 Im using a method call repeated substitution so then i found a close form for f(n)

f(n)= f(n − 1) + 2n − 1 =f(n-2)+4n-4 =f(n-3)+6n-8 .... =f(n-i)+2^in-d

and then by taking i=n i came out with f(n)=f(0)+2^(n+1)-d and can conclude that is has a time complexity of O(2^n) since f(0) and d are all constants.

however i found the answer should be O(n^2) and where did i do wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math was wrong.

```
f(n) = f(n - 1) + 2n - 1
f(n) = f(n - 2) + 4n - 4
f(n) = f(n - 3) + 6n - 9
...
f(n) = f(n - i) + 2i n - i^2
```

When i = n you have:

```
f(n) = f(n - n) + 2n n - n^2
     = f(0) + (2 - 1) n^2
     = n^2
```

Therefore, f(n) is O(n^2)

However you are mistaken. This is not the time-complexity of the function, which is O(n) since that's how many recursions it has, this is the function's order, which means how "quickly it diverges". O(n^2) means the function diverges at a quadratic rate.

Comment: thanks, i know where i did wrong but for the constant 1 ,4 ,8 it does not go up by i^2 the next term is actually 13,19,26 goes by 1+3,+4+5+6... i know this wouldn't matter with final answer but how could i prove that f(n+1) holds considering this

Comment: @dddsuman well that's certainly different than what you originally posted which was 1, 4, 9, ...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hi..I am having one doubt to clear about your statement as **This is not the time-complexity of the function, which is O(n) since that's how many recursions it has, this is the function's order, which means how "quickly it diverges**. while reading another post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation#)

In the mentioned link it says that the time complexity are "n^2" or "n" etc.
Can you please clear how to find time complexity for recursive then? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's because each recursive call in that link has a time complexity dependent on n. Since this function is only a direct recursive call to itself, each function call is O(1) but since the amount of recursions is equal to n, the time complexity for the function is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question.  The complexity of calculating the value is O(n), because you can just do the calculation starting from 0:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 0 + 2*1 - 1 = 1
f(2) = 1 + 2*2 - 1 = 4
f(3) = 4 + 2*3 - 1 = 9
```

Actually, you probably get the idea . . . the nth value is n^2.  I am guessing in the context of the problem that this is what they want the answer to be.  However, to calculate it seems to be O(n).

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's not time complexity, it's just the order of the function