# Time complexity of recursive function with multiple branches

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation), we know how to determine the complexity for recursive function.

However, for the codes below,

```
const int N = 100, W = 100000;
int p[N][W + 1];  // the values of element in the array p are 0, 1, 2. 
int output[N];  

void find_path(int n, int w, int k) {
    if (n < 0) {
        for (int i=0; i<k; ++i) cout << output[i];
        return;
    }

    if (p[n][w] == 0) {
        find_path(n-1, w, k);  // the 1st branch
    }
    else if (p[n][w] == 1) {
        output[k] = n;
        find_path(n-1, w-weight[n], k+1); // the 2nd branch
    }
    else if (p[n][w] == 2) {
        output[k] = n;                    // the 3rd branch
        find_path(n-1, w-weight[n], k+1);
        find_path(n-1, w, k);
    }
}
```

Here is my analysis:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + a   // the 1st branch
       T(n-1) + b   // the 2nd branch
       2*T(n-1) + c // the 3rd branch
```

At the first glance, the 3rd branch takes more time than the other two branches, **Could I just ignore the 1st and 2nd branch?**, so the complexity could be `T(n)=2*T(n-1)`, and the result is `O(2^n)`, **Am I right?**

Moreover, what if there is one more `find_path` invocation in the 2nd branch

```
    else if (p[n][w] == 1) {
        output[k] = n;
        find_path(n-1, w-weight[n], k+1); // the 2nd branch
        find_path(n-1, w, k+1);
    }
```

**How to compute the time complexity in this case?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should take their maximum (for the worst case), which corresponds to the third branch. Because of that, you can ignore the 1st and 2nd branches. Then, the recurrence is `T(n)<=2T(n-1)+O(1)`, so that `T(n)=O(2^n)`.

For the same reason, you can add the new call to the 2nd branch "for free".