# Big-O complexity recursion Vs iteration

Tags: recursion, iteration, big-o, computer-science

Question 5 on [Determining complexity for recursive functions (Big O notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation) is:

```
int recursiveFun(int n)
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i+=2)
        // Do something.

    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + recursiveFun(n-5);
}
```

To highlight my question, I'll change the recursive parameter from `n-5` to `n-2`:

```
int recursiveFun(int n)
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i+=2)
        // Do something.

    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + recursiveFun(n-2);
}
```

I understand the loop runs in `n/2` since a standard loop runs in `n` and we're iterating half the number of times.

But isn't the same also happening for the recursive call? For each recursive call, `n` is  decremented by 2. If `n` is 10, call stack is:

```
recursiveFun(8)
recursiveFun(6)
recursiveFun(4)
recursiveFun(2)
recursiveFun(0)
```

...which is 5 calls (i.e. `10/2` or `n/2`). Yet the answer provided by Michael_19 states it runs in `n-5` or, in my example, `n-2`.  Clearly `n/2` is not the same as `n-2`. Where have I gone wrong and why is **recursion** different from **iteration** when analyzing for Big-O?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common way to analyze big-O of a recursive algorithm is to find a recursive formula that "counts" the number of operation done by the algorithm. It is usually denoted as `T(n)`.

In your example: the time complexity of this code can be described with the formula:

```
T(n) = C*n/2                                   +    T(n-2)
       ^                                              ^
    assuming "do something is constant        Recursive call
```

Since it's pretty obvious it will be in `O(n^2)`, let's show `Omega(n^2)` using induction:

Induction Hypothesis:

```
T(k) >= C/8 *k^2  for 0 <= k < n
```

And indeed:

```
T(n) = C*n/2 + T(n-2) >= (i.h.) C*n/2 + C*(n-2)^2 / 8
     = C* n/2 + C/8(n^2 - 4n + 2) =
     = C/8 (4n + n^2 - 4n + 2) =
     = C/8 *(n^2 + 2)
```

And indeed:

```
T(n) >= C/8 * (n^2 + 2) > C/8 * n^2
```

Thus, `T(n)` is in `big-Omega(n^2)`.

Showing big-O is done similarly:

Hypothesis: `T(k) <= C*k^2` for all `2 <= k < n`

```
T(n) = C*n/2 + T(n-2) <= (i.h.) C*n/2 + C*(n^2 - 4n + 4) 
     = C* (2n + n^2 - 4n + 4) = C (n^2 -2n + 4)
```

For all `n >= 2`, `-2n + 4 <= 0`, so for any `n>=2`:

```
T(n) <= C (n^2 - 2n + 4) <= C^n^2
```

And the hypothesis is correct - and by definition of big-O, T(n) is in O(n^2).

Since we have shown T(n) is both in O(n^2) and Omega(n^2), it is also in `Theta(n^2)`

---

Analyzing recursion is different from analyzing iteration because:

1. `n` (and other local variable) change each time, and it might be hard to catch this behavior.
2. Things get way more complex when there are multiple recursive calls.