# How to find the time complexity of the following code?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Could you explain how to find time complexity of the folowing code? Any help appreciated.

```
int boo(n) {
    if (n > 0)
    {
         return 1 + boo(n/2) + boo(n/2);
    }
    else 
    {
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation

Comment: @DanielCorzo Thank you Daniel, I've already seen that. The situation here is a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Sometimes it is good to write it down. When you start, it sum 1 + boo(n/2) + boo(n/2), which is on the second line.

And each of that n/2 is run also

etc. etc.

So at the end, while the number of calls is growing exponencially, the number of repetions is only logharitmic, which at the end remove each other and you got O(N).

PS : It is enough to count down the last line, the whole tree has always only once time more nodes (minus one), which in complexity theory is neglible (you dont care about constants, which multiplicating by two is)

Comment: This exact question comes in exam LOL thanks again @libik

Comment: :D:D:D yeah, you are right. Actually that is exact binary tree traversing, I remembered it when I see your answer was same with binary tree traverse complexity. So no doubt.