# Java - Big O of bit manipulation?

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

**What is the Big O of this code?** I know all the lines are O(1), except for the recursion part. I'm not sure what the big O of the recursion is, I have a feeling it is still O(1) since we have no lines that are worse than O(1), but usually recursion is O(n).

**Code:**

```
public int getSum(int a, int b) {

        if (b == 0){
            return a;
        }

        if (a == 0){
            return b;
        }

        int add = a ^ b;
        int carry = (a&b) << 1;

        return getSum(add, carry);
    }
```

**Edit:** This is not homework by the way, it is to prepare myself for interviews.

Comment: Remember, Big O is the _worst case scenario_ run time. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation

Comment: I think the recursion calls a maximum of 32 times, because than `carry == 0` for sure, because of the bit shift you run out of bits. So to speak. Thus O(1).

Comment: @jerrybibo - it doesn't have to be. You can just as well define big O for best and average run times too.

Comment: `Big O` simply is just a way to answer **How much space or time does it take to run the code?**.

Comment: @martijnn2008 Yes, I believe that is correct. I'm hoping a third person can verify this.

Comment: @martijnn2008 write your answer, and I'll give it best answer.

Comment: `O(1)` is a *Constant complexity*, how that can be in this case @martijnn2008 because there is a recursive method at the end which not every time invoked! I think it's a *Linear complexity*  `O(n)`! for example *1 time invocation : 1 second*  *10 time: 10 seconds* and so on.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes I realized that those questions cannot be asked here, thank you for bringing that to my attention. I deleted the question.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback - and your positive reaction. Not everybody reacts in such a manor ...

Answer (score 3):

This function is actually `O(n)` worst case. As discussed in the comments above, **big O notation** references the asymptotic upper bound of the function. The upper bound of this function in the worst case is that each of your input numbers is a `max int`. That means the function is called a number of times equal to the number of bits in an integer. If your integer has `32 bits`, then the function runs *32 times*, each time executing a series of constant operations. That makes the function `O(n)`, where `n` is the *size* of your integer.

Comment: I like your answer. However, `n` cannot grow infinitely. Maybe the question was more clear with something like a bitarray.

Comment: Were discussing an algorithm, which is theortical. The fact that OP chose to artificially limit the size of the input doesn't change that fact that the algorithm grows linearly with that input. Imagine you needed to sort an array, but the array was always the same size. You wouldn't then call sorting a constant time algorithm.

Comment: As discussed in the comments, big O notation does not necessarily refer to worst-case analysis.

Comment: @olivercharlesworth, I think you're confusing big O notation with the other elements of Bachmann-Landau notation. While some of these terms have multiple or disputed definitions (Omega for instance), I am using the CLRS definitions of these symbols, which classifies big O as the asymptotic upper bound of the function. For brevity's sake I am using the term "asymptotic upper bound" interchangeably with "worst case".

Comment: @JaysonBoubin - So I guess the issue is that "asymptotic upper bound" does not mean "worst case"; they're orthogonal concepts.  (As an example, the asymptotic upper bound *average case* complexity of quicksort is O(n log n), the worst case is O(n^2).)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I see what you're saying. I still believe, however, that the function described above is O(n). The asymptotic upper bound of the function is is based on the input size, even though for some inputs of any size we may get a constant running time. I will update my answer to relate the fact that we are looking at big O worst case, but I believe that saying that this function is generally be O(1) is against the spirit of this type of analysis. For instance, big O best case of insertion sort is n, but nobody considers insertion sort to be a O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @JaysonBoubin *"function is is based on the input size"* What size? What is `n`? Since Big O describes correlation between "n" and time (in this case), what is correlation between inputs `a` and/or `b` to number of recursion? [There is no correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479259/5221149).

Comment: @andreas, The algorithm moves recursively over the bits stored in an integer, which ends up being int b in the input. The asymptotic upper bound worst case running time is based directly on the number of bits in b. Just because b is a fixed size doesn't mean that the algorithm runs in constant time. Imagine how this would work if the inputs were bit arrays instead of integers. I think you will see what I am saying if you think about it like that.

Comment: @JaysonBoubin I do and I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479259/5221149), which is _O(log n)_, where n is the larger of the two inputs. It is only _O(n)_ if you define `n` as bit-length of the largest input.

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to analyze the complexity of a recursive algorithm, it often helps to find some way in which the "size" of the inputs drop over time. For example, if you're analyzing a recursive factorial implementation, then you'd probably notice that the size of the input drops by one on each call, then use that to say that there are O(n) total calls and therefore that O(n) total work is done.

This recursive function is a bit tricky to analyze because it's not at all clear what quantity is decreasing over time. The value of the first and second arguments both can increase as the function runs, which is generally not a good thing when you're using recursion!

However, there is a useful observation here. Look at the value of the second argument to the recursive function. It's recomputed each time as

```
b = (a & b) << 1
```

which has a very interesting effect: the number of 0 bits at the end of the binary representation of b increases by at least one on each function call. To see this, imagine that b ends with k 0 bits. Computing `a & b` will produce a number whose last k bits are zero, then shifting the result right by one step will increase the number of rightmost 0s by one.

At the same time, the algorithm will terminate when number of rightmost 0s in the binary representation of b exceeds the position of the leftmost 1 in the binary representation of a. To see why, note that we keep ANDing b with a, and as soon as the 1 bits in b get higher than the 1 bits in a the AND evaluates to 0 and the base case triggers.

Putting this together, we can see that the number of recursive calls made is bounded by the position of the highest 1 bit in the number a, since each iteration moves the 1 bits in b higher and higher and the recursion stops when those 1s move past the 1s in a.

So now the question is what that means from a big-O perspective. If you have a number n and write n in binary, the position of the highest 1 bit in n is O(log n), since the meaning of that bit grows exponentially as a function of time. Therefore, the runtime here is O(log n), where n is the maximum of the two inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If we analyse your function, we find the following:

- If one of the two integers passed to it is a **zero** -> it will be invoked ***one time only*** by the return statement at the beginning.
- If the integers passed are **similar** even if they are not zeros -> it will be invoked ***one time only***. That is because of the `XOR` or `^` which requires the two corresponding bits to be *different*. For example:

  ```
  (decimal)    (binary)              (decimal)    (binary)
      5     =    101                     1     =    001
      6     =    110                     1     =    001
  **********************   Whereas    *********************
      3     =    011                     0     =    000
  ```
- If the integers passed are *not* zeros and *not* similar -> that will take the program to the **carry part** and here we need to consider the following:

  1. If the two integers have *no* similar corresponding bits -> `(a&b)` will equals **zero**, thus the method will be invoked **only one time**. For example:

     ```
     (decimal)    (binary)               (decimal)    (binary)
         1     =    001                      1     =    001
         2     =    010                      3     =    011
      **********************   Whereas   *********************
         0     =    000                      1     =    001
     ```
  2. If `(a&b)` results with no zero -> here we come to the *shift part* `<<`
     and here is the plot. If **ALL** the above conditions pass -> then we have a maximum of ***32*** bit shift and supposing that after each *shift* the recursion happens -> we have a maximum of ***32*** recursion **BUT NOT** always. That means it could be not the case every time (sometimes there would be no recursion as I showed above!).

---

So, I believe it's either `O(1)` or `O(n)`, and if we analyse both cases we find:

- **`O(1)`** means **Constant complexity**, for example:

  ```
  1 invocation  : 1 second
  10 invocation : 1 second
  100 invocation: 1 second
  And so on..
  ```

  But that is not the case as I showed above, because every input *may* cause a recursion and *may not*! And the recursion is not the same, although the maximum is *32* but it can be *between 0 to 32*.
- **`O(n)`** means a **Linear complexity**, for example:

  ```
  1 invocation  : 1 second
  10 invocation : 10 seconds
  100 invocation: 100 seconds
  And so on..
  ```

**I** conclude ***The more recursion happens, The more time it takes***.

Though, I'm still open to correction.

Comment: I've got a different bound than what you've proposed. Can you explain why it's obviously either O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree, answer is *O(log n)*.

Comment: Scaling factors are ignored in big-O notation. N is the length of the input, not its value. Answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

First let me quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.
>
> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their running time or space requirements grow **as the input size grows**.

You ask if performance is *O(n)*. Well, before we can answer that, what is `n`?

As you can see above, `n` is usually defined as the *size* of the input. Although that usually refers to the *number* (count) of inputs, in this case, that could be defined as the *magnitude* of `a` or `b`, so the question is: Does the processing time (i.e. number of recursions) increase as `a` is increased and/or as `b` is increased?

<del>The answer is no. There is no correlation between the *magnitude* of `a` or `b` and the number of recursions. Sure, the number of recursions vary, but it is unrelated to *size*.</del>

Whether `n` is `a` or `b`, you have O<sub>min</sub>(1), O<sub>avg</sub>(6.24), and O<sub>max</sub>(33).

---

**UPDATE**

However, you can't get 33 iterations with low values of `a` and `b`. Number of iterations are limited by the bit-length of the larger input. The bit-length would be log<sub>2</sub>(n), which gives the answer:

**O(log n)** where `n = max(a, b)`

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far. It all comes down to the definition of *N.* Which is he length of the input. Not its value,

Comment: `O<sub>max</sub>(33)` is equivalent to `O(1)` as this notation ignores constants.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret `n` to be the number of bits to the left of, and including, the right-most 1-bit of the value `b`.  As `n` grows, so does the number of possible recursive iterations.  In that light, complexity is O(n).