# Big O Proof, how to?

Tags: big-o

I don't understand how to find the complexity of this function. How do I set up the math. Could you please help me out with general tips as well, since I'm very confused with big O notation
Thanks

The answer should be O(n^(1/3))

```
void fun (int n){
 int i=0; 
   while(i*i*i<=n){
     i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: hint: at what fraction of N will the loop terminate?

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467808/6854069

I'm assuming you are trying to calculate time complexity. In that case, if your while loop is

```
while(i<=n){
    i++;
}
```

then it will take "n" iterations for "i" to reach the value "n". Hence the time complexity is O(n).

Since you are trying to reach "n" at the rate of i^3, the time you will take to reach the value of "n" is i^(1/3). O(n) representation of this is O(n^(1/3)). Your while loop can also be represented as:

```
while(i<=n){
    i++;
    i = i*i*i;
}
```

**O(n) representation for time complexity = the number of iterations you take to reach the desired value.**