# Determine time-complexity of recursive function

Tags: time-complexity

Can anybody help me find time conplexity of this recursive function?

```
int test(int m, int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return m;
    else
        return (3 + test(m + n, n - 1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really important to understand recursion and the time-complexity of recursive functions.

The first step to understand easy recursive functions like that is to be able to write the same function in an iterative way. This is not always easy and not always reasonable but in case of an easy function like yours this shouldn't be a problem.

So what happens in your function in every recursive call?

- is n > 0?
- If yes:

  - m = m + n + 3
  - n = n - 1
- If no:

  - return m

Now it should be pretty easy to come up with the following (iterative) alternative:

```
int testIterative(int m, int n) {
    while(n != 0) {
        m = m + n + 3;
        n = n - 1;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Please note: You should pay attention to negative `n`. Do you understand what's the problem here?

**Time complexity**

After looking at the iterative version, it is easy to see that the time-complexity is depending on `n`: The time-complexity therefore is O(n).

Comment: correct but condition of While Loop should be : (n != 0). thanks :)

Comment: Just changed it. Thanks for the hint @MohammadFardin.

Answer (score 1):

The `test(m+n, n-1)` is called n-1 times before base case which is `if (n==0)`, so complexity is `O(n)`

Also, this is a duplicate of [Determining complexity for recursive functions (Big O notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation)