# JS: Optimal flattening function big O notation

Tags: javascript

I am working through creating a flatten function on my own and I came up with this:

```
function flatten(newArr, result = []) {
   for (let x = 0; x < newArr.length; x++) {
      if (Array.isArray(newArr[x])) {
         flatten(newArr[x], result) 
      } else {
         result.push(newArr[x])
      }
   }
     return result
}
```

Are there any pitfalls here that I am missing?  I assume the big O would be O(n) since this is a linear loop that depends on the numb

Comment: but its recursive - its not `o(n)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation

Comment: I think it will be O(N), where N is total number of elements (including nested arrays). It's recursive, but it only 'touches' every element once.

Comment: This was a variadic complexity, that tend to O(n ** k) where k is de deep of arrays that are merging with your elements. If we have a function that flattlen 1 level of deep, and each element of nested 1 level has the same numbers of element k, we have O(n * k). This function are dinamically chaining deep arrays, this can be a hard problem to determine the complexity, because dependes of your input.