# Big O Time Complexity of Code Snippets Python

Tags: python, big-o

I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm still not that good at determining Big O time complexities of some programs. I would like to ask for some help. Here are some code snippets that I had a hard time knowing what the Big O is, and what I think the Big O is:

Code 1: O(n)

```
def foo(n):
   i = 0
   k = 0
   for i in range(0,len(n)):
      for j in range(0,k):
         n[i] = k + 1
         k = 0
   k += 1
```

Code 2: I actually have no idea here

```
def bar(x,i,j,y):
   if j >= i:
      foo = (i+j) // 2
      if x[foo] == y:
         return foo
      elif x[foo] > y:
         return bar(x,i,foo-1,y)
      else:
         return bar(x,foo+1,j,y)
   else:
      return -1
```

Code 3: O(m)

```
def count(a,b):
   # Let len(a) = m
   # Let len(b) = n
   count = 0
   for char in a:
      if char in b:
         count += 1
   return count
```

And if you would, kindly drop some tips on finding the Big O of programs similar to these code snippets.
Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 1
Let N be the length of `n`.
This code will be `O(N)` but it won't do anything since the inner for loop does iterate over `range(0,0)`.

Code 2
Let `N` be the length of `x`.
Supposed that `i` and `j` are in a range that list `x` has the index for.
Worst case scenario is that `y` is not in `x` and `j - i` are as great as possible. That would take about `O(j-i)` which is no more than `O(N)`. Thus on average, this process takes `O(N)` or less.

Code 3
If `char in b` take `O(1)` that might be the case but I don't think so. It might take `O(n)` so the algorithm is `O(mn)`

For a simple algorithm, just count the loop manually.
If recurrence is in the algorithm, using a kind of equation and count how many times should it iterate may help.
Here's related question: [Determining complexity for recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation)

Comment: Hmmm, so does that first code have a constant time complexity? or is it still O(N)?

Comment: It still O(N) since you still loop over `len(n)`.