# Difference between recursive calls and normal calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, notation, function-call

Let there be a function f();

```
void f(int n)
{
  if(n<=1)
    return;
  f(n-1);
  f(n-1);
}
```

I have 2 major questions regarding this code:

1. What is the total number of recursive calls?
2. What is the total number of calls?

and also What is the time complexity of this code?

Basically, I want to understand difference between calls and recursive calls and whether total calls also include the recursive calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining complexity for recursive functions (Big O notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation)

Comment: @dahiya_boy no it does not answer my question.

Comment: Try drawing a recursion tree and/or using the master theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll concentrate on your terminology question

> Basically, I want to understand difference between calls and recursive
> calls and whether total calls also include the recursive calls.

Then the rest is counting, which you can surely do yourself.

A recursive call is a call that comes from the same function. So, e.g. your function `f()` contains two recursive calls, both being `f(n-1)`.

If someone calls `f(4)`, then that is one non-recursive call (not coming from inside `f()`), and, via `f(n-1)` it causes a lot of recursive calls, where f() calls itself.

So:

- Total calls = calls, counts both non-recursive as well as recursive ones.
- Recursive calls are those that come from inside `f()`.