# What is the complexity of the given function

Tags: python, function, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

can someone tell me what is the complexity in the function and why please?
Thanks

```
def func1(n):
    if n==0:
        return (1)
    if n==1:
        return (1)
    if n==2:
        return (2)
    return (n*func1(n-3))

n=int(input())
func1(n)
```

I think the complexity is: "O(nlog n)"

Comment: For all positive `n`s, there will be at most `n / 3` iterations of the loop (you have a *tail recursion*). That, however, is still linear time - O(n).

Comment: @JanezKuhar, this is *not* tail recursion (but near). The last operation isn't a call to `func1()`, it is the multiplication by `n`.

Comment: You would typically write `return 1`, rather than `return (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the function is O(n) because n - 3 is linear. It would be O(logn) if it was a dividing operation. For further explanation, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467808/7470786).

P.S. multiplication with n itself does not affect the given parameter in each recursive call therefore, it does not affect time complexity at all.