# How to estimate the Time Complexity of generating string Permutations using Recursion tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, permutation

The following code prints all permutations of a string:

```
void permutation(String str) {
    permutation(str, "");
}
    
void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-permutations-string/) analyzes the time complexity of the code by determining:

- the function gets called `n!` times in its base case
- the for-loop runs `n` times
- as a result, there will be no more than `n * n!` factorial nodes in the recursion tree.
- each function call corresponds to `O(n)` work, therefore the total time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup> * n!).

I know that the time complexity can be estimated by multiplying the number of nodes in the recursion tree by the amount of work each function call does. If I use the formula branches<sup>depth</sup>, to estimate the number of nodes in the recursion tree, I get n<sup>n</sup> nodes in the recursion tree, which is quite different from `n * n!`.

I'd like to know why branches<sup>depth</sup> isn't a tight bound for this problem, and in which cases I shouldn't use O(branches<sup>depth</sup>) to estimate the time complexity of a function that makes multiple calls.

Comment: The number of branches correlates with the current recursion depth; their sum is constant. So there is really only one variable, and it's easy to see that n! is an accurate count of the number of calls. As a first approximation to an answer, you shouldn't use  `branch**depth` unless they are both constant throughout the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Recursion Call Tree

The formula **`branches ^ depth`** is applicable for time-complexity analysis when each recursive call spawn the ***same number of branches***. Like, for instance, a recursive implementation for [***`N'`th***  Fibonacci sequence member](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node16.html). Where every call either terminates or creates **exactly 2** *new branches* of execution and the time complexity will be **O(2^n)**.

The tree of recursive method calls for the code listed in the question is shown below (*remained characters on the left, prefix is on the right*).

[image]

As you can see, the number of *branches* decreases from top to bottom (from **`n`** to **`1`**), because the number of *characters* hasn't been used yet decreases.

#### Permutations

The number of **permutations** of the given `String` of length `n` is `n!`.

Let's explore ***why*** with a simple example.

Imagine that you need to pick **`1`** card from the standard deck of cards of size **`52`**. I.e. there are **`52`** possibilities to chose from.

After the *first card* has been picked, you need to choose the next one, and there's a **`51`** way to make this choice.

That means that the total number of ways of how **2 cards** can be picked is **`52*51`**.

Then, for the *third card*, we have only **`50`** cards remaining in the deck.

That means that there are **`52*51*50`** ways to choose **3 cards** from the deck.

For **four cards**, that number will be **`52*51*50*49`**, for **five** - **`52*51*50*49*48`**, and so on.

That is a so-called **proof by induction** that there are **`52*51*50*49*48*...*3*2*1`** (*and that is a factorial - **`52!`***) ways to pick **`52`** cards from the deck.

Now, you might think of each *character* in a *string* as if it's a *card* and the *string* itself is a *deck* of size `n`. Similarly, there will be **`n!`** way to pick all `n` *characters* from this *string*.

#### Algorithm - costs of operations

Since the number of **permutations** is `n!` that means that we need to generate `n!` *strings* of length `n`.

Each *string* has to be constructed letter by letter:

```
prefix + str.charAt(i) // append a charactor at position `i` to the `prefix` string
```

In order to create a *string* of length `n`, we need to pick a *character* `n` times in a loop. Each step of iteration will spawn a recursive method call. Therefore, **`n*n!`** method calls will be required to construct all `n!` *permutations*.

There's an additional cost that contributes to the total time complexity.

Creation of the remaining string (*characters that are not picked yet*) requires to invoke

```
str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1)
```

at each method call. And that will cost **O(n)** time because in order to create a substring we have iterated over the source string and copy up to `n - 1` characters from its underlying array into the new string.

Therefore, the overall time complexity will be **O(n^2*n!)**.

Comment: I appreciate you explaining the intuition behind why the number of permutations is  O(n^2*n!). However, I was more curious about how I could derive this information by drawing the recursion tree.

Comment: @WarrenCrasta I've updated the with the method call tree.

Answer (score 0):

As [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) suggested in the comments, branches<sup>depth</sup> doesn't seem to be a good estimation  when the number of branches for a node varies based on the recursion depth, as seen in this problem.

For this problem, it seems that a better way to estimate the number of nodes is to use the formula described by [@Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754982/shubham) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation/43991156#43991156):

> Complexity = length of tree from root node to leaf node * number of leaf nodes

When I draw the recursion tree of this function for a string of length n, I see that there are n! leaf nodes. The depth of the recursion is n, so the total number of nodes is `n * n!`. As mentioned in the question, since each function call corresponds to O(n) work, therefore the total time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup> * n!).